# Is there a Session Timeout Exception in Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-security, sessiontracking

That would be useful, so that I don't have to check if session is valid before interacting with the currently login user. Even nicer if I could tell Spring to automatically redirect user to the login page if sesssion is already timed out.

There's a similar question here:[Logout/Session timeout catching with spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843010/logout-session-timeout-catching-with-spring-security)
 but what I really need is something more intuitive and elegant. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Actually

```
<form-login login-page='/login.jsp'/>
```

will already do this. If the user requests a secured page and is not logged in (that also happens when the session isn't available due to a timeout), spring security sends a redirect to the specified `login-page`.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-form-and-basic

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to secure all my protected resources and see if it works like that.