# How to listen on logout in Spring Security + JSF

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security

I want to listen on logout/timeout and set `lastSeen` to User object. How can I achieve this?

I saw and tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18128496/3287459), but it's for Spring MVC and it didn't work for me in JSF. I'm using MyFaces 2.2, Spring 4 and Spring Security 3.5.

Comment: You might need to expand your question, but you shouldn't need anything fancy to do this. a simple [`HttpSessionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) should suffice

Comment: That should work in your environment as well, this has nothing to do with Spring MVC. It is a Spring Application listener which works in any spring based environment.