# ApplicationListener<SessionDestroyedEvent> is not called

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to audit timeout logOut event, I searched a bit and find a solution. But it doesn't work. The event method is not called at all when the user logs out or timeout.

This is my code:
ObjectLock.java:

```
@Component
public class ObjectLock implements ApplicationListener<SessionDestroyedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(SessionDestroyedEvent event)
    {
        List<SecurityContext> lstSecurityContext = event.getSecurityContexts();
        String userName;
        for (SecurityContext securityContext : lstSecurityContext)
        {
          userName = (String)securityContext.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
          System.out.println("Log Out " + userName);
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Application.java:

```
 public class Application {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication( Application.class );
        application.addListeners(new ObjectLock());
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = application.run(args);
      //  ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
      }
    }
```

Anyone can tell me what is wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following code/class and then the listener will get called:

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletListenerRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher;

@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {
  @Bean
  public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
  }
}
```