# Spring WebFlow shows JSF ajax response as plain text

Tags: jsf, spring-webflow

I have a web application using Spring WebFlow and JSF. My web has list page and details page. At details page I click save button (command button of PrimeFaces) when session was expired. System render to login page. I clicked login to go to list page. After that I navigator to details page. System displayed like below:

```
<partial-response>
<changes>
<update id="mandateForm">
<![CDATA[
<form id="mandateForm" name="mandateForm" method="post" action="/rrs-web/web/creditReport?execution=e3s1" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"> <input type="hidden" name="mandateForm" value="mandateForm" /> <h2>Mandatsträger</h2> <div class="tableSection left">
]]>
<![CDATA[
<div class="right mb05"><a id="mandateForm:j_idt350" href="#" class="ui-commandlink button01 add-management-board" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'mandateForm:j_idt350',update:'searchPersonForm',oncomplete:function(xhr,status,args){openDialogBoardsMembers(event);}});return false;">hinzufügen</a> </div> <h3>Geschäftsleitung</h3> <div class="clr"></div><table id="mandateForm:tblManagementBoard" class="table01"> <thead> <tr> <th class="alignleft w64" scope="col">Nachname</th> <th class="alignleft w60" scope="col">Vorname</th> <th class="alignleft w54" scope="col">Wohnort</th> <th class="alignleft w90" scope="col">Funktion</th> <th class="alignleft w52" scope="col">Gremium</th> <th class="alignleft w60" scope="col">Quelle</th> <th class="alignleft w80" scope="col">ConsumerTyp</th> <th class="alignleft w90" scope="col">OFWI-ID</th> <th class="aligncenter checkbox" scope="col"><abbr title="Verlustscheine">VS</abbr></th> <th class="aligncenter checkbox" scope="col"><abbr title="Pfändungen">PF</abbr></th> <th class="aligncenter checkbox" scope="col"><abbr title="Konkurskünstler">KK</abbr></th> <th class="aligncenter checkbox" scope="col"><abbr title="Privatkunkurs">PK</abbr></th> <th class="aligncenter checkbox" scope="col">IJ-bad</th> <th class="alignleft w36" scope="col">Aktion</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr><td></td></tr></tbody> </table> </div> <div class="clr"></div> <div class="tableSection left"> <div class="right mb05"><a id="mandateForm:j_idt400" href="#" class="ui-commandlink button01 add-company-representatives" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'mandateForm:j_idt400',update:'searchPersonForm',oncomplete:function(xhr,status,args){openDialogBoardsMembers(event);}});return false;">hinzufügen</a> </div> <h3>Firmenvertreter</h3> <div class="clr"></div><table id="mandateForm:tblCompanyRepresentatives" class="table01"> <thead> <tr> <th class="alignleft w64" scope="col">Nachname</th> <th class="alignleft w60" scope="col">Vorname</th> <th class="alignleft w54" scope="col">Wohnort</th> <th class="alignleft w90" scope="col">Funktion</th> <th class="alignleft w52" scope="col">Gremium</th> <th class="alignleft w60" scope="col">Quelle</th> <th class="alignleft w80" scope="col">ConsumerTyp</th> <th class="alignleft w90" scope="col">OFWI-ID</th> <th class="aligncenter checkbox" scope="col"><abbr title="Verlustscheine">VS</abbr></th> <th class="aligncenter checkbox" scope="col"><abbr title="Pfändungen">PF</abbr></th> <th class="aligncenter checkbox" scope="col"><abbr title="Konkurskünstler">KK</abbr></th> <th class="aligncenter checkbox" scope="col"><abbr title="Privatkunkurs">PK</abbr></th> <th class="aligncenter checkbox" scope="col">IJ-bad</th> <th class="alignleft w36" scope="col">Aktion</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr><td></td></tr></tbody> </table> </div> <div class="clr"></div> <div class="tableSection"> <h3>weitere HRMandatsträger (gruppiert)</h3><table id="mandateForm:tblMandateHolder" class="table01"> <thead> <tr> <th class="alignleft w100, alignleft" scope="col">Funktion</th> <th class="alignleft w100, alignleft" scope="col">Anzahl Mandatsträger</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr><td></td></tr></tbody> </table> </div> </form>
]]>
</update>
<update id="javax.faces.ViewState">
<![CDATA[ e3s1 ]]>
</update>
</changes>
</partial-response>
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Just don't use JSF and Spring webflow together. JSF and Spring MVC are equivalent technologies, so go with one of them. JSF has its own flow (navigation) API.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But I can not change this framework because it is client's requirement. My problem is sending ajax request (of PrimeFaces) when session was expired. My command button in details page like below:

Comment: <p:commandButton id="btnSave" value="Save" action="saveTaskStatusData" update=":#{p:component('mandateForm')}"  />. If I remove "update" attribute, system will run ok. I did find one topic that I think it helped I solve that problem. Here is that topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143539/jsf-2-spring-security-3-x-and-richfaces-4-redirect-to-login-page-on-session-tim