# How to set a custom invalid session strategy in Spring Security

Tags: spring-security

I'm developing a web application, based on Spring-Boot - 1.1.6, Spring -Security -3.2.5 and more.

I'm using Java based configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityCtxConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Bean
    DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint delegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher, AuthenticationEntryPoint> map = new LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher, AuthenticationEntryPoint>();
        Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint defaultEntryPoint = new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint();
        map.put(AnyRequestMatcher.INSTANCE, defaultEntryPoint);
        DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint retVal = new DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint(map);
        retVal.setDefaultEntryPoint(defaultEntryPoint);
        return retVal;
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        ExceptionHandlingConfigurer<HttpSecurity> exceptionHandling = http.exceptionHandling();
        exceptionHandling.authenticationEntryPoint(delegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint());
        http.logout().logoutSuccessHandler(new LogoutSuccessHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication arg2)
                    throws IOException, ServletException {
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The requirement is to return Http status 401 in case that the session cookie is invalid or missing(no matter the reason)
I see the `InvalidSessionStrategy` but I don't find a way to set it on the `SessionManagementFilter`.
Can some one please instract me how to implement my plan or another one that will fulfill the requirement

Comment: did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

Using SpringBoot this works for me:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class UISecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        ...
        http.addFilterAfter(expiredSessionFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class);
        ...
    }

    private Filter expiredSessionFilter() {
        SessionManagementFilter smf = new SessionManagementFilter(new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository());
        smf.setInvalidSessionStrategy((request, response) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Session go BOOM!"));               
        return smf;
    }
}
```

Comment: From Spring Security 4,2+, this can be done in XML configuration, in security http section using element session-management and invalid-session-strategy-ref attribute.

Comment: @pedorro, Thank you, this works in Spring security 5.1.4 as well :-)

Answer (score 6):

We had the exact same problem and I did this hack to solve it (yes I know, this is a hack, therefore the name...).
I create a `BeanPostProcessor` and search for the `SessionManagementFilter` to reconfigure it...

```
@Bean
public HackyBeanPostProcessor myBeanPostProcessor() {
    return new HackyBeanPostProcessor();
}

protected static class HackyBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
        // FIXME check if a new spring-security version allows this in an
        // other way (current: 3.2.5.RELEASE)
        if (bean instanceof SessionManagementFilter) {
            SessionManagementFilter filter = (SessionManagementFilter) bean;
            filter.setInvalidSessionStrategy(new InvalidSessionStrategy() {

                @Override
                public void onInvalidSessionDetected(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
                    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                }
            });
        }
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Comment: this solution works and should be mentioned as solution

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using AspectJ (I mean, compile time weaving and not Spring AOP), it was quite easy to hack the `SessionManagementFilter` creation by setting my custom `InvalidSessionStrategy` after the `SessionManagementFilter` is constructed:

```
@Aspect
public class SessionManagementAspect {
    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog();

    @AfterReturning("execution( org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.new(..))&&this(smf)")
    public void creation(JoinPoint pjp, SessionManagementFilter smf) throws Throwable {
        logger.debug("Adding/Replacing the invalid session detection policy to return 401 in case of an invalid session");
        smf.setInvalidSessionStrategy(new InvalidSessionStrategy() {

            @Override
            public void onInvalidSessionDetected(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
                logInvalidSession(request, "invalid cookie");
                if (!response.isCommitted())
                    response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If you are not using AspectJ, try adding `@Component` and add this Aspect to your context, it might work if the `SessionManagementFilter` is a bean (Since Spring-AOP applias only on spring beans)